# Reading A Long From A File After Parsing [C#]

Tags: c#, file, parsing, long-integer

I am trying to read from a file that is structured as such:

`VariableName:14326A6AC
Value:Long
Value:Long`

I am trying to read it doing it as listed below, but I get a format error. When I add the formatting for hexadecimal (the format the longs are in) they are converted to decimal. Is there a way to keep them as a long so I don't have to do the long conversion from decimal to hex?

```
public static long returnLineValue(string lineName)
        {
            var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                if (line != null)
                {
                    char split = ':';
                    if(line.Contains(lineName))
                    {
                        string[] s = line.Split(split);
                        return Int64.Parse(s[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Add a breakpoint at *return Int64.Parse(s[1]);* and check the s's content, it must not be a number.

Comment: can you provide  input(sting) sample?

Comment: @DavitTvildiani I added the exact input that is not working.
s[1] = 14326A6AC

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
return Convert.ToInt64(s[1], 16)
```

16 is base 16 (hexadecimal). This function convert from a hexadecimal string to a long.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to keep it in hexadecimal form? It's returning 5421573804 instead of 14326A6AC.

Comment: You can only keep that form if it is string. This will convert a number to hex form: `long k = 5421573804; string hex = k.ToString("X");` you will get `"14326A6AC"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow *hexadecimal values* in `Parse`:

```
...
// The same Parse but with hexadecimals allowed
return Int64.Parse(s[1], NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
...
```

whenever you want to *represent* `Int64` in hexadecimal form, use *formatting*:

```
  Int64 value = 255;

  String result = value.ToString("X"); // "X" for hexadeimal, capital letters

  // "FF"
  Console.Write(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   return Int64.Parse(s[1],System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```